# How can I make the faces of my cube smoothly transition between all colors of the rainbow?

Tags: c++, colors, hex

I have a program in Visual Studio that is correctly rendering a 3D cube that is slowly spinning. I have a working FillTriangle() function that fills in the faces of the cube with any color whose hex code I enter as a parameter (for example, 0x00ae00ff for purple). I have set the color of each face to start at red (0xFF000000), and then I have a while loop in main() that updates the scene and draws new pixels every frame. I also have a Timer class that handles all sorts of time-related things, including the Update() method that updates things every frame. I want to make it so that the colors of the faces smoothly transitions from one color to the next, through every color of the rainbow, and I want it to loop and do it as long as the program is running. Right now, it is smoothly transitioning between a few colors before suddenly jumping to another color. For example, it might smoothly transition from yellow to orange to red, but then suddenly jump to green. Here is the code that is doing that right now:

```
...
main()
{
...
float d = 0.0f; //float for the timer to increment

 //screenPixels is the array of all pixels on the screen, numOfPixels is the number of pixels being displayed
 while(Update(screenPixels, numOfPixels))
 {
   ...
   timer.Signal(); //change in time between the last 2 signals
   d += timer.Delta(); //timer.Delta() is the average current time
   if(d > (1/30))    // 1 divided by number of frames
   {
     //Reset timer
     d = 0.0f;
     
     //Add to current pixel color being displayed
     pixelColor += 0x010101FF;
   }
   ...
 }
 ...
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this? Adding to the current pixel color was the first thing that came to my mind, and it's kind of working, but it keeps skipping colors for some reason.

Comment: Look at the HSV color model and its conversion to RGB. Varying the hue part will go through all colors smoothly.

Comment: How can I see its color model? It sounds like once I see that, I can add to the color being displayed.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. You look up the HSV color model on wikipedia or wherever you like and how to convert it to RGB. Then you implement it in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That constant is going to overflow with each addition.  Not just as a whole number, but across each component of the color spectrum: R, G, and B.

You need to break your pixelColor into separate Red, Green, and Blue colors and do math on each byte independently. And leave Alpha fixed at 255 (fully opaque). And check for overflow/underflow along the way. When you reach an overflow or underflow moment, just change direction from incrementing to decrementing.

Also, I wouldn't increment each component by the same value (1) on each step. With the same increment on R,G, and B, you'd just be adding "more white" to the color.  If you want a more natural rainbow loop, we can do something like the following:

Change this:

```
 pixelColor += 0x010101FF;
```

To this:

```
 // I'm assuming pixelColor is RGBA

 int r = (pixelColor >> 24) & 0x0ff;
 int g = (pixelColor >> 16) & 0x0ff;
 int b = (pixelColor >> 8)  & 0x0ff;

 r = Increment(r, &redInc);
 r = Increment(g, &greenInc);
 g = Increment(g, &blueInc);

 pixelColor = (r << 24) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | 0x0ff;
```

Where redInc, greenInc, and blueInc are defined and initialized outside your main while loop as follows:

```
int redInc = -1;
int greenInc = 2;
int blueInc = 4;
```

And the increment function is something like this:

```
 void Increment(int color, int* increment)  {
     color += *increment;
     if (color < 0) {
         color = 0;
         *increment = (rand() % 4 + 1);
     } else if (color > 255) {
         color = 255;
         *increment = -(rand() % 4 + 1);
     }
 }
```

That should cycle through the colors in a more natural fashion (from darker to brighter to darker again) with a bit of randomness so it's never the same pattern twice.  You can play with the randomness by adjusting the initial colorInc constants at initialization time as well as how the `*increment` value gets updated in the `Increment` function.

If you see any weird color flickering, it's quite possible that you have the alpha byte in the wrong position. It might be the high byte, not the low byte.  Similarly, some systems order the colors in the integer as RGBA. Others do ARGB.  And quite possible RGB is flipped with BGR.

Comment: Thank you! It's definitely a lot closer now. It's only going between yellow, white, blue, and black at the moment, but I'll keep messing with the values.

Comment: What is it that the randomness does here? Does it just affect the pattern of the colors, or does it also impact the actual color being displayed?

Comment: As for the randomness, if you incremented R, G, and B, at the same rate, it would just pulsate from white to black within a single shade.  You wanted a rainbow, right?

Comment: Oops - I had a typo in the pixelColor assignment.  It should be `pixelColor = (r << 24) | (g << 16) | (b << 8) | 0x0ff;`  I updated the code sample above to reflect.

Comment: Just to be sure my RGBA ordering assumption is correct, what color gets shown if you set `pixelColor = 0x0000FFFF` on each frame?  Is it, solid blue, solid red, or black?  Similarly, what is `pixelColor=0xFFFF0000` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping the result will be a rainbow. I totally missed that typo, thanks! When I set pixelColor = 0x0000FFFF on each frame, it's a solid light blue, and if I set it to 0xFFFF0000 on each frame, it's a solid red.

Comment: Something's aumcks.  If 0000FFFF is blue, that implies RGBA.  But if FFFF0000 is solid red, that implies ARGB.  Which is it?  Can you post the code that actually sets the texture color?

Comment: Yes, but there's a bit to it. I have a .h helper file that sets some variables, and that is where pixelColor is set:
`unsigned int pixelColor = 0xFF000000;`

Comment: There's a spot in my main cpp file where I set the texture color of the faces of the cube. It works based off of a switch statement that takes in a number, and sets a bool based off of that number. If I press 5, that's when it turns on the rainbow color mode.